# Index files in CWP Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, centos, centos-web-panel, cwp

I have a CentOS server with CWP. I would like on a website that I have on the server that when they access example.com/test and the test folder does not contain any index file that shows the index with the other files.
Do I have to configure any parameter in .htaccess?
Right now I'm getting an Error 403.The permissions folder has 775 so you should not have a permission problem. Thank you

Comment: In your `.htaccess` file you need to allow "indexing"  --  `Options +Indexes`

Answer (score 0):

If you have root access you can Fix permissions for the respective user account. If example.com/test folder is empty an index.html will be created in that folder.

If you don't have root access you can create a `.htaccess` directory-level configuration file in example.com/test to allow access to specific files you prefer viewable.